# Using PHP to add avariable to a mysql select statement breaks the statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code used on a php page, I am at the point of just trying to get it to work, it runs the first query fine(which is an insert) and returns the correct value to $orderid
 
But it will not return anything for the select query next, if I take out the variable $myorderid and put in a number it will return the expected results, but as soon as I try to use a variable it returns nothing. 
 
I have tried using mysql_escape_string, sprintf and now the intval methods but nothing seems to work.
No error is returned from mysql just an empty result set.

```
mysql_query($sSQL) or print(mysql_error());
$orderid = mysql_insert_id();

$myorderid =    $orderid;
$myquery = "SELECT cartOrderID, Sum(pDonationAmt) as amount 
FROM products INNER JOIN cart ON ( cartProdID = pID ) 
WHERE cartOrderID = " . intval($myorderid). " GROUP BY cartOrderID ";

$myresults = mysql_query($myquery);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myresults)) 
  { error_log('orderid inserted is:.$orderid.' OrderID in   mysql:'.$row['cartOrderID'].' and the total is: '.$row['amount'], 3, 'inc/atestingdata.txt'); }
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old 'echo' can help ... try:

```
$myquery = "SELECT cartOrderID, Sum(pDonationAmt) as amount 
 FROM products INNER JOIN cart ON (pID = cartProdID) 
 WHERE cartOrderID = $orderid GROUP BY cartOrderID ";
echo $myquery;
```

Comment: Yes the query has the number in it from the variable when I echo it back or even when I send it to a log. But it seems to disappear when it gets sent to the database.

Comment: Another DUH moment with this one, the cartOrderID was not actually set yet when I sent my query. (about twenty lines too early).

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the `intval($myorderid)` with quotes `'`,

```
 $myquery = "SELECT cartOrderID, Sum(pDonationAmt) as amount 
 FROM products INNER JOIN cart ON ( cartProdID = pID ) 
 WHERE cartOrderID = '" . intval($myorderid). "' GROUP BY cartOrderID ";
```

Comment: No go, I believe I tried it already, but I did it again and still 0 results are returned.